# compile error for node-expat.cc (part of the thing system)

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to cross compile TTS (which is a js application for node.js) for an arm platform.   I have nodejs compiled and installed fine, however, when I try to compile the TTS system, I get the following:

```
../node-expat.cc:54:34: error: 'Arguments' does not name a type
   static Handle<Value> New(const Arguments& args)
```

I've googled it and found a posts with suggestions (install older nodejs, update npm's bundled node-gyp), but no one has bothered to explain what the cause of the problem is.  Regardless, the suggestions do not seem to have any effect.   Does anyone know where Arguments is supposed to come from, and why it's not showing up on my system?

Comment: `Arguments` is [`v8::Arguments`](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1Arguments.html).

Comment: any ideas why my system would not be able to see this?  (I'm assuming it's something to do with namespace.   I did not modify this code, and I assume it works in normally, so something in my build environment has to be off..)

Comment: I have no experience compiling Node addons on ARM, but it _may_ be related to that. Which module exactly are you trying to install?

Comment: I'm trying to cross-compile The Thing System for an ARM8 processor.   It seems to encounter this problem during the configure stage of xml2json/node_modules/node-expat.   I'm not sure how to go about even debugging this.  I'm missing some key information like where v8 is supposed to come from (does it come from the local nodejs on the build machine, or the cross-compiled version), what configurations might effect this, and likely some other infromation I don't know to look for...

Comment: Since addons depend on `v8.h` (plus a few dozen others too), they should be installed on your ARM (assuming that you're running the install there). On my Mac the include files are located in `/usr/local/include/node`, but I assume they are part of your cross-compilation "package" (but that's about as far as I can help you I'm afraid).